# Android Annotations @UiThread race conditions?

Tags: android-annotations

```
@UiThread
void foo() {
   ...some animations...
};

@UiThread
void bar() {
   xyz();
};

@UiThread
void xyz() {
   foo();
};
```

Can i get in trouble if i use many of these nested @UiThread methods in my app?

Can i get some race conditions because of that?

Will it only impact performance?

Answer (score 2):

`@UIThread` will generated a method which uses a `Handler` to execute the code, like this :

```
private Handler handler_ = new Handler();
public void bar() {
    handler_.post(new Runnable() {
        ...
    }
}
```

If we take a closer look to the [Handler's javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), we can see this paragraph :

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

The Handler is created while the class is instantiated, so it will be linked to the main thread. And as each call to an `@UIThread` annotated method will be enqueue to this Handler, each method will be executed one after the other.

So you shouldn't have any race conditions in these methods. And as these methods will be executed on the main thread, you must do only UI processing.

I hope I answer all your questions.